Nuxt build error: "createRequire" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external"
Keep getting the following error during build:
Nuxt Build Error: ../../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Cyk9bIUq.js (50:9): "createRequire" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "../../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Cyk9bIUq.js".

"nuxt": "^3.13.2",
"vite": "^5.2.11",
I just don't understand that, if its something vite needs, it should just be imported?

It seems that one of your dependencies uses createRequire, which is an API from node that does not exist in the browser.
